# How to define the type of keys of object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am making to return a object as below.
I want to define type of key value of object.
But This doesn't work at all.
Could you give me some advice ? Thank you for reading it.

```
class Config {
  private username: string;
  private password: string;
  private database: string;
  private host: string;
  private dialect: string;
  private DBConfig: object;

  constructor() {
    this.username = "";
    this.password = "";
    this.database = "";
    this.host = "";
    this.dialect = "";
    this.DBConfig = {};
  }

  public getDBConfig(environment: string): Object {
    switch (environment) {
      case "local":
        this.DBConfig = {
          username: "root",
          password: "1234",
          database: "test",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          dialect: "mysql",
        };
        break;
    }
    return this.DBConfig;
  }
}

export { Config };
```

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by _But This doesn't work at all._?

Comment: @pzaenger when I put number in 'password', it doesnt catch type error.

Comment: @ThomasJason it does not catch the error because you are passing your numbers as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface:

like this ->

```
export interface IdBConfig {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    database: string;
    host: string;
    dialect: string;
}
```

and than create your object inside class ->

```
    private DBConfig: IdBConfig;
```

so you can inicialize it on constructor, like you did: =>

```
   this.DBConfig = {
      username: "root",
      password: "1234",
      database: "test",
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      dialect: "mysql",
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a proper interface for that instead of `object`.

For example define `DBConfig` and also you need to care about the case when `this.DBConfig` can be `undefined`.

```js
// define an interface
interface DBConfig {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  database: string;
  host: string;
  dialect: 'mysql';
}

class Config {
  private DBConfig?: DBConfig; // <- specify it as a type of property.

  public getDBConfig(environment: 'local'): DBConfig; // <- an override for the 100% case.
  public getDBConfig(environment: string): DBConfig | undefined; // <- an override for other unknown cases
  public getDBConfig(environment: string): DBConfig | undefined { // <- implementation
    switch (environment) {
      case "local":
        this.DBConfig = {
          username: "root",
          password: "1234",
          database: "test",
          host: "127.0.0.1",
          dialect: "mysql",
        };
        break;
    }
    return this.DBConfig;
  }
}

export { Config };
```

Comment: You can also remove the whole private attributes (`username`, `password`, ...) of `Config`. Just keep them in `DBConfig`.